# ng-repeat in div not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've recieved the active_content from backend and the response is fine as an array as confirmed from console.log. But however, the `ng-repeat` over here doesn't seem to be working. I'm trying to display the class details in a tile like design so that each class has its own tile with respective details.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div ng-repeat="content in active_content" class="col-md-3">
     <div class="info-tile">
        <div class="tile-heading" style="font-size:30px"><span>{{content.class}}-{{content.division}}</span><span ng-if="content.stream"> | {{content.stream}} </span></div>
        <div style="font-size:20px;text-align:right;"><span>{{content.studentCount}} students</span></div>
        <div style="font-size:20px;text-align:right;padding-bottom:7%;"><span>5 absentees</span></div>
        <div class="tile-footer" style="font-size:13px;"><a  href="#" class="text-danger" ><span ng-show="content.classTeacherGender= 'M'">Mr.</span><span ng-show="content.classTeacherGender == 'F' ">Mrs.</span> {{content.classTeacherfName + " " + content.classTeacherlName}}</a></div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

AngularJS

```
var co_data = {};

   co_data.token = $cookies.get("myToken");



           $http({
             method  : 'POST',
             url     : 'Here goes my php service ',
             data    : co_data,
             headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            })
            .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
         if(response.data.status){

               $scope.isContentFound = true;             
               $scope.active_content = response.data.response;
               console.log("Active Content", $scope.active_content);

          }

           else{ 
              $scope.isContentFound = false;      
              $scope.active_content = {};
           }
              }); 
          }
        $scope.fetchContent();
```

Chrome Console

```
Active Content 
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{class: "01", division: "A", classTeacherfName: "Abhijith", classTeacherlName: "C S", classTeacherGender: "M", …}
1
:
{class: "02", division: "A", classTeacherfName: "FAVAZ", classTeacherlName: "M", classTeacherGender: "M", …}
2
:
{class: "04", division: "A", classTeacherfName: "RITHWICK", classTeacherlName: "ANIL", classTeacherGender: "M", …}
3
:
{class: "05", division: "A", classTeacherfName: "MANJU", classTeacherlName: "ANIL", classTeacherGender: "M", …}
4
:
{class: "11", division: "B", classTeacherfName: "Anas", classTeacherlName: "Jafry", classTeacherGender: "M", …}
5
:
{class: "12", division: "A", classTeacherfName: "SHAHIL", classTeacherlName: "NUHMAN", classTeacherGender: "M", …}
6
:
{class: "10", division: "C", classTeacherfName: "SAIRAB", classTeacherlName: "RAHMAN", classTeacherGender: "M", …}
```

Comment: what is the controller code?

Comment: show the controller code

Comment: I've edited the code. do check and reply

Comment: Show a sample of what you have got with this `console.log("Active Content", $scope.active_content);`

Comment: "doesn't seem to be working" isn't helpful: what isn't working? Specifically: what do you expect the code to do? What is it doing? What have you ruled out as possible causes? Can you provide a re-create that shows the issue? (Yes: you may need to re-write just enough to show the issue in isolation.)

Comment: Make sure this is the correct object to get the data : response.data.response

Comment: try using scope.$appy() or putting your array assignment in $timeout to give it time to update.

Comment: @Hey24sheep i've tried it, it doesn't seem to be working still

Comment: can you reproduce your error in a plunker or fiddle or snippet here? so we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

In your ng-repeat write this..

```
ng-repeat="content in active_content track by $index"
```

or,

```
ng-repeat="content in active_content track by content.class"
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you have Duplicate Key in Repeater
try

```
ng-repeat="content in active_content track by $index"
```